# undefined local variable or method `f' in Rails and Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a new map, and it's not working out so far:

```
undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#<Class:0x007ff46c0b12c0>:0x007ff46d777ba8>
```

I'm using Paperclip. The new page form:

```
<%= form_for @map, :url => maps_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |form| %>
  <% if @map.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@map.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this map from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @map.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :carname %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :carname %>
  </div>
    <%= form.file_field :map %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :criticalcomponentlocations %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :criticalcomponentlocations %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :warnings %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :warnings %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :additionalinfo %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :additionalinfo %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you pass `form` variable to the block passed to `form_for` method, you should substitute `f` with `form`.

Comment: I am doing something similar, getting error "undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass"..
can you help

Comment: @Suraj apparently the object you pass to `form_for` is `nil`.

Comment: I am not able to detect the issue actually.
adding my answer here as a question

Comment: @Suraj I already told you what's your issue. Don't do it, ask another question instead.